# luatex doesn't stop on error on Windows, but does on ubuntu

Tags: errors, windows, ubuntu

I use TeXworks on Win7 (Version 0.6.5, MikTex 21.1) and TeXworks on Ubuntu (Version 0.6.5, "launchpad").
And I have a tex file with an error (undeclared control sequence).

Running luatex (1.13.0) on Ubuntu stops because of this error, on Win7 (1.10.0, Tex Live 2019) it runs over it and only shows the error in log file and console output. But without any stop.

Why this difference? Are there any standard commandline options passed to luatex, which can be different on different systems? Where can I find and change them?

Or is it because of the version 1.13.0 and 1.10.0?

Calls of luatex in the TeXworks-preferences are the same on both machines ($synctexoption, $fullname).

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: tex always stops by default on an error check your editor is not passing in a commandline option such as  `-interaction=batchmode` that will make it scroll past errors

Comment: yes, I checked in TeXworks-preferences. Don't know where to look else.